# Extending/Integrating existing Spring application with iOS and Android

Tags: java, android, ios, spring

I'm looking for advice about mobile application development.  I already have a Spring application running that uses spring security (OAuth) for authenticating user and lands into a dashboard showing HR related data and expense data for monthly invoice management.

I would like to build an iOS and Android application that would use the already built Java Spring security service for authenticating user and use/share session for other services for same backend and database as well. Any advice or guide with some tips or examples would be much helpful? Thanks you,

Comment: If your Spring app exposes a REST API you're in good shape: any user interface only needs to know URLs and HTTP requests to send and how to consume the response that comes back.  I'd recommend that you look at spring.io guides for Spring Boot examples.

Comment: Thanks duffymo My doubt is specific to authenticated user session (object with roles). 

If one user has role-a and another user has role-b they see different dashboard menu. How do I maintain that user principle after authenticating an user through rest API unlike I do it in spring setting authenticated user principle into session?

Comment: Use Spring Security.  Keep services and UI separate.